# Is it possible to set non-modifiable (constant) item in the localStorage? If so, how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

It's a rare case, but is it possible to set the item in the localStorage so that it's not modifiable even on the same domain? If not, is there any work around? eg. listening for localStorage access event and cancel the event on local storage access to that particular variable?

I know it's a weird case and may be not possible, but any ideas?

Sample use case:

> You are creating a platform where third party developers can create
>   apps and add them to the same domain. You want appPolicy to be
>   available through localStorage, but you don't want other developers to
>   modify it.

Comment: I don't think local storage is the way to go about what you're after.  If you want to add global variables for developers to access, but they can't store modified values, just give them an include that's required to develop for the site and put all your vars in there.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store read-only data in localStorage. However, if you want read-only properties in JavaScript, you can make them private, and expose them via privileged methods. For example:

```
function Person() {
    var ssn = '123-456-7890';  // private; cannot be accessed from outside the class

    // privileged method. has access to private data, and is publicly available  
    this.getSSN = function() {
        return ssn;
    }
}
```

Once you create an instance of `Person` there is no way (that I know of) to change `ssn`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: There's no way to change ssn, but there's a way to change what getSSN returns: `var person = new Person(); person.getSSN = function () { return '000-000-0000'`

Comment: @MaxNanasy: Good point, I hadn't though of that. Fortunately, you can prevent that by sealing the constructor, and its prototype, e.g. `Object.seal(Person); Object.seal(Person.prototype)`. Note that this only works in ES5-compatible browsers.